# How do you combine check constraint with an IF statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, check-constraints

How do I use check constraint in SQL when I want to put a constraint like this:

```
Y must be NOT NULL when X=‘hello’;
when X != ‘hello’ Y can be NULL
```

I tried like this but it didn’t work..

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD ( CONSTRAINT cons CHECK ( X= ‘hello’ and Y!= NULL or X!= ‘hello’));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the logic, the correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT cons
    CHECK ( X = 'hello' and Y IS NOT NULL NULL OR X <> 'hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD CONSTRAINT cons CHECK ( Y IS NOT NULL OR X <> 'hello');
```

Then if you have:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( x VARCHAR2(5), y VARCHAR2(5) );
```

Then you can insert these values:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( x, y )
SELECT 'hello', 'abc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'other', 'abc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'other', NULL  FROM DUAL;
```

But if you try to:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( x, y ) VALUES ( 'hello', NULL );
```

You get the exception:

> ```
> ORA-02290: check constraint (SCHEMA_NAME.CONS) violated
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ff6e1a113617e1e89a2d64f7f166ae9c)*